# the spring security redirect securing pages to its host not zuul host

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

i have two applications zuul and uaa.

the uaa redirects the authentication page to its own domain and not to the zuul domin which proxies the uaa.

For example, when I enter `revotubezuul.cfapps.io/uaa/home` it redirects me to `revotubeauth.cfapps.io/uaa/signin`. This is the uaa service itself, while I expect it to redirect to `revotubezuul.cfapps.io/uaa/signin`.

I didn't face this problem when I ran on localhost. It only occurs when deployed on the Pivotal cloud.

example code https://github.com/ashraf-revo/revotube

any idea ! how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you. In my spring security configuration. with "*defaultSuccessUrl*" like this, after success authentication it will go to "*localhost:8080/login/success*"

> .defaultSuccessUrl( "/login/success")

So I just change to

> .defaultSuccessUrl( "**http://zuullocalhost:8081**/login/success")

It works for me.